# What are the best places on the body to cool off during exercise?

Tags: cool-down, overheating

My wife is making me some "cooling" clothes out of material from Frogg Toggs (evaporative cooling towels).

I think the best places to have that are:

1. Back
2. Neck (all the way around)
3. Lats (along my side)
4. My forearms up to just above my elbow (interior of my arm "inside" the elbow more so than the outside)
5. Temples would be good but a bit hard to keep cloth there (and it's a very small surface area)

[image: demonstration]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about making clothes